# What is the UK correspondence to this job

Tags: united-kingdom, job-hunting, qualifications

In my home country, Portugal, there is a job title that translates into something like "Health and Safety at Work Technician".

This technician is someone that works for a company and knows about security laws and standards that must be regarded at work, ensuring that at the company the security measures are being applied, workers are safe and the company doesn't break any security law.

What is the corresponding job for this in the UK? If I was to look for a job having these qualifications, what should I look for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think "health and safety officer" would fit nicely. I have known people with that job title before, and they were required to know all the latest 'health and safety in the workplace' legislation and regulations, as well as recommendations and guidelines.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use job websites such as reed, monster to look for jobs that of similiar. The main UK Gov website that you can check which is the closet to your job role can be found here: http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/classifications/current-standard-classifications/soc2010/index.html